# Regarding restarting instance mongodb

Tags: mongodb

while restarting the mongodb instance the directory mongodb in /var/run is deleting after restarting the instance the again i am creating the directory in /var/run and restarting the service whats the solution to it not to delete the directory after restarting the instance

Comment: At normal system that directory is not removed automatically, you startup script must do it.. Why, I don't know. However, same way you can create it at the startup script.

Comment: My version is 3.4.3 can you provide me a startup script for for scheduling the script

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/init.d) you can find startup/stop init.d script

Edit mongod -script file:    `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.4.3/bin/
PIDDIR=/var/run/mongod
PIDFILE=$PIDDIR/$NAME.pid`

In the mongod -script file add line
`mkdir -p $PIDDIR ; chown -R $PIDDIR` before start-stop-daemon line (at `star_server()` section)

edit your `/etc/mongod.conf` file, so it have

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid
```

start your mongodb with command `sudo service mongod restart`

Comment: After adding the script  while starting the service as service mongod start it showing error as Could not find /usr/bin/mongod

Comment: Fix `DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod` line to point right place.. Hey! It cannot be that hard to read little bit what script says!!!  Use `find` command of your text editor to locate `/usr/bin`.